# Why the `memcached_servers ` do not have `http://` in front of the address?

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

In the `/etc/glance/glance-api.conf`, why the `memcached_servers` do not have `http://` in front of the address, you see the `auth_uri` and `auth_url` all have.

```
[keystone_authtoken] 
＃... 
auth_uri  =  http：// controller：5000 
auth_url  =  http：// controller：35357 
memcached_servers  =  controller：11211 
auth_type  =  password 
project_domain_name  =  default 
user_domain_name  =  default 
project_name  =  service 
username  =  glance 
password  =  GLANCE_PASS
```

Comment: …because they aren't HTTP servers?

Comment: @duskwuff what protocal it use?

Comment: The memcached protocol. It's its own thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably because they don't communicate over http?

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

Memcache appears to communicate over a custom protocol over TCP.

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped